# Как в GoogleShets записать дату в другую таблицу с помощью скрипта?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица "Тест" и "DB".

В таблице "Тест", Лист "А" при выполнении скрипта нужно переместить данные с ячейки B2 в таблицу "DB", Лист "В" в пустые ячейки "B2:B" нужного нам ID "A2:A" из предыдущей таблицы "А2". (Изображение 1)

[image: Изображение 1]

И если данные там уже имеются, не записывать ничего. (Изображение 2)

[image: Изображение 2]

Результат правильной работы скрипта. (Изображение 3)

[image: Изображение 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Ключ таблицы А')
    .getSheetByName('Имя нужного листа в таблице A');
  var sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Ключ таблицы B')
    .getSheetByName('Имя нужного листа в таблице B');
  var valueId = sheetA.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var valueData = sheetA.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var arrayId = sheetB.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var ln = sheetB.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
    var cache = arrayId[i][0];
    if (cache == valueId) {
      if (sheetB.getRange(i + 1, 2).getValue() == '') {
        sheetB.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(valueData);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажешь почему полученная дата в формате "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ 02:00:00". Как просто получить просто дату?

Comment: Выделить весь столбец и применить Формат - Числа - Дата
http://joxi.ru/823aa0psJ9gLDr

Comment: Работает. Еще вопрос: Дату вносит в ячейку которая нужна и почему то в пустую пред идущую, почему это происходит? Просто данные должны писаться именно в зависимости от ID.

Comment: Это странно. Только что проверил у себя, с копипастой кода из ответа. Не могу воспроизвести проблему. Доберусь домой вечером, подумаю в чем может быть дело.

Comment: После изменения ячеек в формат "Дата", пишет в каждую ячейку не зависимо от Есть ли там данные или нет.